# How to set consumer priority with AmqpTemplate

Tags: spring-amqp

I'm using the `spring-boot-starter-amqp` library to:

- Wait indefinitely until a message can be received.
- Process the message, which may take several minutes.
- Terminate the program

I also would like to the set the [consumer priority](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-priority.html). However, I don't know how to set the `x-priority` consumer argument, as the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#consumer-priority) only mentions how to do this with an asynchronous consumer, not with AmqpTemplate or RabbitTemplate. Any help would be appreciated.

ApplicationRunner class:

```java
private final AmqpTemplate template;
private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

...

@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
  Message message = template.receive("analyses", -1);
  if (message == null) throw new IllegalStateException("No message received");
  byte[] body = message.getBody();
  // todo: process the message
  System.out.printf("[x] Received '%s'%n", new String(body, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  context.close();
}
```

In a configuration class:

```java
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate amqpTemplate(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
  return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently supported; the consumer is created in a private method `createConsumer()` which doesn't pass any arguments to `basicConsume()`.

Please open a new feature issue on GitHub; it won't be difficult to implement and we have releases planned for next week.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues

Comment: Thanks! [Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1533) created.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/pull/1534